# Switch and case statment confusion - Javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm having an issue understanding certain aspects of switch and case in JavaScript. My issue is why does a case sometimes have a string next to it and sometimes why does it not. An example is from FreeCodeCamps course.

Here's the link to it and here is the answer I came up with, I figured it out through trial and error but I don't understand why. What I do understand is that switches are like if / else if. That I do understand.

*I commented next to the code where my confusion was

Link:
https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/replacing-if-else-chains-with-switch

Code:

```
            function chainToSwitch(val) {
              var answer = "";
              // Only change code below this line

              switch(val) {

                case "bob": // Why is this a string?
                  answer = "Marley";
                  break;

                case 42: //Why doesn't this one have quotes around it?
                answer = "The Answer";
                 break;

                case 1:
                answer = "There is no #1";
                break;

                case 99:
                answer = "Missed me by this much!";
                 break;

                case 7:
                answer = "Ate Nine";
                break;

            }

              // Only change code above this line  
              return answer;  
            }
```

Comment: Did you read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: You are matching strings or numbers. The value is not required to be all one type.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean why one case has an int and another has a string, it's because of the differing values of val. It could be "bob", 42, or anything else, and answer is set based on that.

For reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 0):

One flaw of older Javascript versions is that variables can be any type. This is considered a flaw because the type of a variable has the possibility to change, and can confuse the reader. Your question is a perfect example of why Javascript has extended languages, such as typescript, that make it type safe.

You are correct a switch statement is like an if statement. It is checking for ints and strings because the variable val can be any type. The first case checks if val holds the string value "bob, the second case checks if val holds the integer value 42, and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it doesn't make a difference if its "bob", bob, 162, its just the way that the course made me write it so I can pass and go to the next lesson? - Seems like I just simply over thinking the "WHYS" so I don't get confused.

Comment: Good job on figuring it out.